# PHP gettext cant change language temporary

Tags: php, gettext

In my project I want to send notification emails to multilingual recipients. For this case gettext is already setup and works fine for the website. Every user has a locale attribute, containing his language setting. My code looks like:

```php
$users = [User, User, User, User];

foreach($users as $user) {

   $userLocale = $user->getLocale(); // e.g. en_US, de_DE

   putenv("LC_ALL=".$userLocale);
   setlocale(LC_ALL, $userLocale);

   $content = _("Hello there");

   $user->sendNotificationMail($content);
}
```

That code ignores the language just set and translates the string always to <s>its default language</s> the first language set in the loop. (in this case german)

But when I hardcode `putenv("LC_ALL=en_US");` it works.

What to I miss here?

**EDIT:**

Seems like php cant switch the language as many times as I want.
First switch is successfull but the following switches seems to fail or gettext doesnt take the changes in consideration.

My testcode:

```php
$payload = "";

putenv("LANG=en_US");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US");
$payload .= _("Add")." - ".getenv("LANG");

putenv("LANG=it_IT");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "it_IT");
$payload .= _("Add")." - ".getenv("LANG");

putenv("LANG=de_DE");
setlocale(LC_ALL, "de_DE");
$payload .= _("Add")." - ".getenv("LANG");

//output: Add - en_USAdd - it_ITAdd - de_DE
//moving de_DE to the top
//output: hinzufügen - de_DEhinzufügen - en_UShinzufügen - it_IT
```

wtf is going on?
I tried also to delete the first variable setting of `$payload`. Then all following gettext calls will use the second language setted.

Comment: The thing is, even if I do `getenv("LC_ALL")` its says the correct user locale…

Comment: Are you sure, that `->getLocale()` method returns something?

Comment: Indeed, it does. `getenv()` spits out that just set env variable.

Comment: Have you specified path to your translation table?

Comment: Yes. The translation works fine for the whole website. I just want to temporarily switch the language for sending mails. Isnt it weird that it makes a difference when I hardcode the locale code instead of taking it from the users object?

Comment: @Mully seems like it works for the first user but the for the following users it doesnt changes the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like that you have to set the textdomain everytime.

```php
putenv("LANG=".$locale);
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
textdomain($domain);
```

Comment: Lifesaver, spent hours trying to debug this issue! Any clue on why this is required?

Comment: I have no idea. Stumbled across this by accident …

Comment: What a good accident! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to send the language code as a parameter in sendNotificationMail() and set the $userLocale inside that method before sending the contend to the client

Comment: Why should that make a difference?

Comment: Doesnt have any effect though.

Answer (score 0):

It did not work for me. Init is done via:

```
public function initTranslation(string $lang = 'de_DE')
{
    putenv('LC_ALL=' . $lang);
    setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang);
    setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'C');
    bind_textdomain_codeset(__NAMESPACE__, 'UTF-8');

    bindtextdomain(__NAMESPACE__, "./Locale");
    textdomain(__NAMESPACE__);
}
```

This works fine for the first setup, but after changing and calling the function, the old language stays active.